# Comparing JSONArrays

Tags: android, json, compare, arrays

I am currently using a custom service in my android application to retrieve a JSONArray from a remote database. Once I have retrieved the JSONArray, I would like to compare its contents to another JSONArray which I call 'mostRecent.' If the newly retrieved JSONArray differs from 'mostRecent' then I would like to update 'mostRecent' with the newly retrieved JSONArray. If I am not mistaken, however, the JSONArray equals method compares the instance of the JSONArray object and not the contents, correct? Is there an easy method to compare the contents of two JSONArrays? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use that:

```
array1.toString().equals(array2.toString());
```

Maybe you will be able to use even the strings you receive without constructing the `JSONArrays`, but then you will need to make sure the two are formatted the same way.

Comment: This is a quick cheat that does work. But caution should be used with large arrays!!! I wanted to invoke an event whenever the data in my arrays changed, so I used this to compare the arrays as strings and just store previous state as a string. However my arrays are small. I think a better way to go about this would be to generate checksums and compare those instead of the data its self.

Comment: Arrays can have different order of items, so it won't work in all times, be careful!

Comment: @AlexanderAgeychenko arrays are ordered collections. If same elements are in different indices, the arrays are different. If you need a different task to be solved, you need a different approach.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev my bad, I've meant JSONObjects, usually we compare JSONArrays of JSONObjects, and in that case JSONObjects could have different order of keys and arrays will be different when casted to `String`

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Can I ask a quick question? would it also work if i use jsonarr1.equals(jsonarr2) without the toString()?