# Comparing two JSONArray and finding differences

Tags: android, json, arrays

([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454064/comparing-jsonarrays) needs for the equality)
But I have two JSONArray and I will check the strings that exists in these arrays and find the different elements.

Normally I can see the values of the arrays like this:

```
JSONArray array1 = getArray1();
JSONArray array2 = getArray2();

// array1 = 12,23,44,66
// array2 = 23,44,66,90

for (int i=0; i < array1.length(); i++) {
   String name=array1.getString(i);
}
```

I need to find elements that exists in `array1` but doesn't exist in `array2`. Array elements are strings.

Answer (score 4):

Create two different Set starting from the two array, then call

```
firstSet.removeAll(secondSet);
```

the result will be the difference between the two arrays.

the doc for `removeAll` says:

> Removes from this set all of its elements that are contained in the
>   specified collection